# (Re-)boot not working after 17.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10, reboot, grub-efi

Having installed an artful upgrade, the first reboot initialized by the upgrader didn't end up in the grub menu as usual but started Windows.

A power cycle led to the grub menu next time letting me boot Ubuntu, but any subsequent reboot from within Ubuntu now ends up in the EFI system settings. Even on exiting the EFI settings by choosing "Discard changes and exit", it will get there again in an endless (as far as I can guess) loop.

So far, the only workaround is to cycle power which works every time bringing up the grub menu but is more than nasty as the power button is out of reach under normal conditions.

Searching for similar reports didn't come up with any results. Is this a known bug, though? What to do to debug this situation?

**UPDATE**

- Meanwhile, the system rebooted normally once.
- The power cycle workaround didn't work once.

---

Some potentially relevant specs and observations:

- dual boot, EFI only on a Samsung 960 Pro (NVMe)

  - installed Windows 10 first and Yakkety afterwards
  - Yakkety and Zesty didn't show any reboot-related problems
- secure boot disabled
- Intel Xeon E5-1650 v4
- X99 chipset
- NVidia binary drivers, hence no wayland
- using GNOME exclusively since the upgrade
- 4.13.0-32-generic kernel
- swap disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (extremely likely) got fixed by upgrading grub from `2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.1` to `2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.2`.